# How to get the function of a Mathematical Pattern

Tags: math, pattern-matching

How do i get a function to calculate the next step? (Does not have to be exact...) What is the best way to approach this?

- 1: about 100ms
- 2: about 400ms
- 3: about 3100ms (3,1 sec)
- 4: about 36500ms (36,5 sec)
- 5: about 305600ms (ca. 5,1 min)
- 6: about 1970981ms (ca. 32,8 min)
- 7: about 13855774ms (ca. 230,9 min or 3,8 hours)
- 8: ?????
- 9: ?????
- **. . . . . . .**

It looks exponential, but with what ratio?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B100,+400,+3100,+36500,+305600,+1970981%5D

#### This is the time a javascript chess minimax algorithm takes (on my computer). Each step is its search tree depth.

Comment: Do an exponential regression (or, more or less equivalently -- take the logs of the times and then do a simple linear regression since if the times are an exponential function of `n` then log(time) is linear in `n`.

Comment: John Coleman's comment is especially useful when you see that WolframApha's Log-linear plot of your data is quite close to a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it in R:

```
> times <- c(100, 400, 3100, 36500, 305600, 1970981, 13855774)
> n <- 1:7
> lm.fit <- lm(log(times) ~ n)
> summary(lm.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = log(times) ~ n)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7 
 0.33742 -0.31605 -0.30811  0.11805  0.20326  0.02751 -0.06208 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.22800    0.22945    9.71 0.000197 ***
n            2.03976    0.05131   39.76  1.9e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2715 on 5 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9968,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9962 
F-statistic:  1581 on 1 and 5 DF,  p-value: 1.898e-07
```

The basic idea is that if `time = A*e^(kn)` then `log(time) = kn + log(A)`. When you do linear regression of `log(time)` as a function of `n`, the coefficient of `n` *is* the growth rate and the intercept is the log of the constant multiple. In this case, the fit is very good (as seen by the R squared statistic of over 0.99) so an exponential model for your data is reasonable. since `exp(2.228)` is approximately 9.28, a good fit for your data is:

```
time = 9.28*e^(2.04*n)
```

Note that "good" is relative. The *absolute* errors in the approximation are rather large though the *relative* errors are small for n = 6 and 7. Furthermore, n = 7 is a small sample size, and generalizing based on that is dangerous. Finally, things like garbage collection might become more significant as n is increased, leading to even longer run-times for e.g. n = 8 or 9 than the formula would predict.